# Presto error 400 when connecting to s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, kubernetes, hive, presto, starburst

**OVERVIEW**

I deploy a Presto cluster on Kubernetes and try to connect it to a S3 bucket through a compatible API.

**HOW TO REPRODUCE**

I use **Presto Operator** (by Starburst) and configure my Presto resource with the following properties :

```
  hive:
    additionalProperties: |
      connector.name=hive-hadoop2
      hive.metastore.uri=thrift://hive-metastore-presto-cluster-name.default.svc.cluster.local:9083
      hive.s3.endpoint=https://<s3-endpoint>
```

And i add the s3-secret with data like AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: **** and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ****

Then, I use **presto-cli** to create a Schema with the following command :

```
CREATE SCHEMA ban WITH (LOCATION = 's3a://path/to/schema');
```

**ERROR**

And it throw an error in the Hive metastore like :

```
Got exception: org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.AWSBadRequestException doesBucketExist on presto: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Bad Request (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: 400 Bad Request
```

**PROBLEM IDENTIFICATION**

I saw on this [link](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.2.0/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/troubleshooting_s3a.html) that "This happens when trying to work with any S3 service which only supports the “V4” signing API —but the client is configured to use the default S3 service endpoint"

And the solution is : "The S3A client needs to be given the endpoint to use via the fs.s3a.endpoint property"

But the property *fs.s3a.endpoint* doesn't work with Presto's Hive configuration.

Does someone already had this problem ?

**USEFUL DETAILS**

- Kubernetes version : 1.18
- Presto Operator image : starburstdata/presto-operator:341-e-k8s-0.35

--- EDIT ---

**FULL STACKTRACE**

```
2020-09-29T12:20:34,120 ERROR [pool-7-thread-2] utils.MetaStoreUtils: Got exception: org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.AWSBadRequestException doesBucketExist on presto: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Bad Request (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: 400 Bad Request; Request ID: txc7f0218a02574ba59ec91-005f732692; S3 Extended Request ID: txc7f0218a02574ba59ec91-005f732692), S3 Extended Request ID: txc7f0218a02574ba59ec91-005f732692:400 Bad Request: Bad Request (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: 400 Bad Request; Request ID: txc7f0218a02574ba59ec91-005f732692; S3 Extended Request ID: txc7f0218a02574ba59ec91-005f732692)
org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.AWSBadRequestException: doesBucketExist on presto: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Bad Request (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: 400 Bad Request; Request ID: txc7f0218a02574ba59ec91-005f732692; S3 Extended Request ID: txc7f0218a02574ba59ec91-005f732692), S3 Extended Request ID: txc7f0218a02574ba59ec91-005f732692:400 Bad Request: Bad Request (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: 400 Bad Request; Request ID: txc7f0218a02574ba59ec91-005f732692; S3 Extended Request ID: txc7f0218a02574ba59ec91-005f732692)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AUtils.translateException(S3AUtils.java:212) ~[hadoop-aws-3.1.1.3.1.0.0-78.jar:?]
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.Invoker.once(Invoker.java:111) ~[hadoop-aws-3.1.1.3.1.0.0-78.jar:?]
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.Invoker.lambda$retry$3(Invoker.java:260) ~[hadoop-aws-3.1.1.3.1.0.0-78.jar:?]
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.Invoker.retryUntranslated(Invoker.java:317) ~[hadoop-aws-3.1.1.3.1.0.0-78.jar:?]
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.Invoker.retry(Invoker.java:256) ~[hadoop-aws-3.1.1.3.1.0.0-78.jar:?]
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.Invoker.retry(Invoker.java:231) ~[hadoop-aws-3.1.1.3.1.0.0-78.jar:?]
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.verifyBucketExists(S3AFileSystem.java:372) ~[hadoop-aws-3.1.1.3.1.0.0-78.jar:?]
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.initialize(S3AFileSystem.java:308) ~[hadoop-aws-3.1.1.3.1.0.0-78.jar:?]
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:3303) ~[hadoop-common-3.1.1.3.1.0.0-78.jar:?]
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:124) ~[hadoop-common-3.1.1.3.1.0.0-78.jar:?]
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:3352) ~[hadoop-common-3.1.1.3.1.0.0-78.jar:?]
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:3320) ~[hadoop-common-3.1.1.3.1.0.0-78.jar:?]
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:479) ~[hadoop-common-3.1.1.3.1.0.0-78.jar:?]
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:361) ~[hadoop-common-3.1.1.3.1.0.0-78.jar:?]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.Warehouse.getFs(Warehouse.java:115) [hive-exec-3.1.0.3.1.0.0-78.jar:3.1.0.3.1.0.0-78]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.Warehouse.getDnsPath(Warehouse.java:141) [hive-exec-3.1.0.3.1.0.0-78.jar:3.1.0.3.1.0.0-78]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.Warehouse.getDnsPath(Warehouse.java:147) [hive-exec-3.1.0.3.1.0.0-78.jar:3.1.0.3.1.0.0-78]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.Warehouse.determineDatabasePath(Warehouse.java:190) [hive-exec-3.1.0.3.1.0.0-78.jar:3.1.0.3.1.0.0-78]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.create_database_core(HiveMetaStore.java:1265) [hive-exec-3.1.0.3.1.0.0-78.jar:3.1.0.3.1.0.0-78]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.create_database(HiveMetaStore.java:1425) [hive-exec-3.1.0.3.1.0.0-78.jar:3.1.0.3.1.0.0-78]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_232]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_232]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_232]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_232]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.invokeInternal(RetryingHMSHandler.java:147) [hive-exec-3.1.0.3.1.0.0-78.jar:3.1.0.3.1.0.0-78]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.invoke(RetryingHMSHandler.java:108) [hive-exec-3.1.0.3.1.0.0-78.jar:3.1.0.3.1.0.0-78]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy26.create_database(Unknown Source) [?:?]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$Processor$create_database.getResult(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:14861) [hive-exec-3.1.0.3.1.0.0-78.jar:3.1.0.3.1.0.0-78]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$Processor$create_database.getResult(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:14845) [hive-exec-3.1.0.3.1.0.0-78.jar:3.1.0.3.1.0.0-78]
        at org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction.process(ProcessFunction.java:39) [hive-exec-3.1.0.3.1.0.0-78.jar:3.1.0.3.1.0.0-78]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.TUGIBasedProcessor.process(TUGIBasedProcessor.java:104) [hive-exec-3.1.0.3.1.0.0-78.jar:3.1.0.3.1.0.0-78]
        at org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(TThreadPoolServer.java:286) [hive-exec-3.1.0.3.1.0.0-78.jar:3.1.0.3.1.0.0-78]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_232]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_232]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_232]
Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Bad Request (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: 400 Bad Request; Request ID: txc7f0218a02574ba59ec91-005f732692; S3 Extended Request ID: txc7f0218a02574ba59ec91-005f732692)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1639) ~[aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.11.271.jar:?]
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1304) ~[aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.11.271.jar:?]
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1056) ~[aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.11.271.jar:?]
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:743) ~[aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.11.271.jar:?]
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:717) ~[aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.11.271.jar:?]
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:699) ~[aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.11.271.jar:?]
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:667) ~[aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.11.271.jar:?]
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:649) ~[aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.11.271.jar:?]
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:513) ~[aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.11.271.jar:?]
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4325) ~[aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.11.271.jar:?]
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4272) ~[aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.11.271.jar:?]
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.headBucket(AmazonS3Client.java:1337) ~[aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.11.271.jar:?]
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.doesBucketExist(AmazonS3Client.java:1277) ~[aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.11.271.jar:?]
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.lambda$verifyBucketExists$1(S3AFileSystem.java:373) ~[hadoop-aws-3.1.1.3.1.0.0-78.jar:?]
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.Invoker.once(Invoker.java:109) ~[hadoop-aws-3.1.1.3.1.0.0-78.jar:?]
        ... 33 more
```

Comment: Do you have full exception stacktrace?

Comment: Yes, I edited my post with the full stacktrace.

Comment: The excetion is coming from HMS, so it depends how you configure and deploy that.

Comment: Bad request does often mean signing problems of some form or other, but also clock skew & other oddness
https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/troubleshooting_s3a.html

Comment: also: that is a stack from the apache S3A connector, not the presto s3 one. So it will support the fs.s3a.endpoint option.

Comment: the property fs.s3a.endpoint is well configured, but i stil have the same 400 error. I try to reach swift s3-compatible API. The same configuration with a minio server works.